# Apache Camel with Slack Integration (Java DSL)

Tags: apache-camel, slack-api, slack

does someobody has an idea with connecting a slack channel to a route?
Is it possible to do it with Java DSL?

Does someone has an example for the configuration of that component?

Answer (score 1):

Apache uses slack incoming webhooks. [This link](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) shows details of how to create an app and set webhooks on.

With your channel able to receive messages your java code may be like this (XXX/YYY/ZZZ will change according to the hook you have created):

```
final CamelContext camel = new DefaultCamelContext();
final SlackComponent slackComponent = (SlackComponent) camel.getComponent("slack");
slackComponent.setWebhookUrl("https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX/YYY/ZZZ");

/* Create the routes */
camel.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
  @Override
  public void configure() {
    from("timer:test?period=2000").setBody(simple("foo")).to("slack:#general");
}});
```

Regarding that the consumer side will not work due slack webhooks limitation, you can only send messages to a channel.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Came appears to support sending messages to slack using an [incoming webhook](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks).

Check the official Apache camel documentation [here](http://camel.apache.org/slack.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have added the camel-slack dependency  in your project, the component is automatically registered in the camel context. You can get the SlackComponent from there and configure it in your extended RouteBuilder:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    //...
    // get the slack component
    final SlackComponent slackComponent = (SlackComponent) this.getContext().getComponent("slack");
    // set the webhook URL
    slackComponent.setWebhookUrl("<yourWebhookUrl>"));
    //...
    this.from("direct:notification").to("slack:#your-channel")
}
```